# Hyper-V import Virtual Machine Linux (No operating system was loaded)

Tags: linux, hyper-v

After importing the virtual machine on which Ubuntu Server was installed:

[screen UEFI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b895i.png)

How to fix a similar problem, where to start and what could be the options? I chose the .vhdx file on which Ubuntu Server was already installed, but nothing starts when importing.

Comment: Does your Ubuntu installation boot with UEFI?

Comment: Try to disable Secure Boot or create a 1st generation of the Hyper-V VM and attach VHDX file

Comment: Initially, there is Ubuntu Server without UEFI, respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to disable Secure Boot or create a 1st generation of the Hyper-V VM and attach VHDX file

It is right. Initially, it was necessary to create a 1st generation virtual machine.